# Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (truediv_17:0) to a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib

I'm trying to program a neuronal network based on the algorithm `Pix2Pix`. At the start when I call the functions of `TensorFlow` an error appears and I do not know how to resolve it.

The functions I call:

```
IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256

def resize(inimg, tgimg, height, width):

  inimg = tf.image.resize(inimg, [height, width])
  tgimg = tf.image.resize(tgimg, [height, width])

  return inimg, tgimg

def normalize(inimg, tgimg):
  inimg = (inimg / 127.5)  - 1
  tgimg = (tgimg/127.5) - 1

  return inimg, tgimg

def load_image(filename, augment=True):

  inimg = tf.cast(tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(INPATH + "/" + filename)), tf.float32)[..., :3]
  tgimg = tf.cast(tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(OUTPATH + "/" + filename)), tf.float32)[..., :3]

  inimg, tgimg = resize(inimg, tgimg, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH)
  inimg, tgimg = normalize(inimg, tgimg)

  return inimg, tgimg

def load_train_image(filename):
  return load_image(filename, True)

def load_test_image(filename):
  return load_image(filename, False)

plt.imshow(((load_train_image(randurls[0])[0]) + 1)/ 2)
```

At the final I want to see the result of a load of my database but appears this error:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-748ce6c46d5c> in <module>()
     31   return load_image(filename, False)
     32 
---> 33 plt.imshow(((load_train_image(randurls[0])[0]) + 1)/ 2)


/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, data, **kwargs)
   2675         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad, imlim=imlim,
   2676         resample=resample, url=url, **({"data": data} if data is not
-> 2677         None else {}), **kwargs)
   2678     sci(__ret)
   2679     return __ret

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1597     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1598         if data is None:
-> 1599             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1600 
   1601         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    367                 f"%(removal)s.  If any parameter follows {name!r}, they "
    368                 f"should be pass as keyword, not positionally.")
--> 369         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    370 
    371     return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    367                 f"%(removal)s.  If any parameter follows {name!r}, they "
    368                 f"should be pass as keyword, not positionally.")
--> 369         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    370 
    371     return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5677                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
   5678 
-> 5679         im.set_data(X)
   5680         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5681         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    678             if isinstance(A, Image.Image):
    679                 A = pil_to_array(A)  # Needed e.g. to apply png palette.
--> 680         self._A = cbook.safe_masked_invalid(A, copy=True)
    681 
    682         if (self._A.dtype != np.uint8 and

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py in safe_masked_invalid(x, copy)
    793 
    794 def safe_masked_invalid(x, copy=False):
--> 795     x = np.array(x, subok=True, copy=copy)
    796     if not x.dtype.isnative:
    797         # Note that the argument to `byteswap` is 'inplace',

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in __array__(self)
    734   def __array__(self):
    735     raise NotImplementedError("Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor ({}) to a numpy"
--> 736                               " array.".format(self.name))
    737 
    738   def __len__(self):

NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (truediv_17:0) to a numpy array.
```

Comment: Instead of `(inimg / 127.5)`, can you try `(inimg / 255)` and check if the error persists. Thanks!